# Add multiple rows for each datetime in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

```
            name_col
datetime          
2017-03-22     0.2
```

I want to add multiple rows till the present date (2017-03-25) so that resulting dataframe looks like:

```
            name_col
datetime          
2017-03-22     0.2
2017-03-23     0.0
2017-03-24     0.0
2017-03-25     0.0
```

How do I add multiple rows for each datetime? I can get present date as

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date
date.today()
```

Comment: I'd recommend you to accept [@NickilMaveli's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43014363/5741205) - it's more idiomatic

Comment: thanks @MaxU, for your solution and also generosity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of [`DF.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) to align the original `DF's` indices to a new range of indices generated for an expanded date range.

Note that [`pd.date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.1/generated/pandas.date_range.html) produces a frequency offset corresponding to daily frequency, and so the need to  not specify this explicitly as it's `freq` parameter.

```
from datetime import date

df.reindex(pd.date_range(df.index[0], date.today(), name=df.index.name), fill_value=0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `.resample()` method:

```
In [98]: df
Out[98]:
            name_col
datetime
2017-03-22       0.2

In [99]: df.loc[pd.to_datetime(pd.datetime.now().date())] = 0

In [100]: df
Out[100]:
            name_col
datetime
2017-03-22       0.2
2017-03-25       0.0

In [101]: df.resample('D').bfill()
Out[101]:
            name_col
datetime
2017-03-22       0.2
2017-03-23       0.0
2017-03-24       0.0
2017-03-25       0.0
```